# Need help debugging this stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've been trying to create the stored procedure as below but I kept getting these errors:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure PKG_BNLX5_INSERT_DMBATCHERRLOG, Line 164
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@V_ERR_REC".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure PKG_BNLX5_INSERT_DMBATCHERRLOG, Line 165
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@V_ERR_REC".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure PKG_BNLX5_INSERT_DMBATCHERRLOG, Line 166
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@V_ERR_REC".
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure PKG_BNLX5_INSERT_DMBATCHERRLOG, Line 167
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@V_ERR_REC".
>   .......
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure PKG_BNLX5_INSERT_DMBATCHERRLOG, Line 172
>   Incorrect syntax near '@V_ERR_REC'.

Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "PKG_BNLX5_INSERT_DMBATCHERRLOG"
    (@IN_PROCNAME VARCHAR(4000),
     @IN_TARNAME VARCHAR(4000),
     @IN_CURSOR VARCHAR(4000),
     @IN_UNIQUE_NUMBER FLOAT,
     @IN_SQLCODE VARCHAR(4000),
     @IN_SQLERRM VARCHAR(4000),
     @IN_REMARK VARCHAR(4000)) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @V_ERR_REC.PROCNAME      = @IN_PROCNAME;
    SET @V_ERR_REC.TARNAME       = @IN_TARNAME;
    SET @V_ERR_REC.CURSOR        = @IN_CURSOR;
    SET @V_ERR_REC.UNIQUE_NUMBER = @IN_UNIQUE_NUMBER;
    SET @V_ERR_REC.DATIME        = GETDATE();
    SET @V_ERR_REC.ERRCODE       = @IN_SQLCODE;
    SET @V_ERR_REC.ERRDESC       = @IN_SQLERRM;
    SET @V_ERR_REC.REMARK        = @IN_REMARK;

    INSERT INTO VM1DTA.DMBATCHERRLOG VALUES @V_ERR_REC;

    COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: I've no SQL Server knowledge, but at a guess (the error message tells you!) you've not declared the @V_ERR_REC record.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't declare any of the variables as referenced in the error messages.  Additionally, it looks like you're trying to set all the parameters to some sort of table that doesn't exist? SQL Server variables don't really work like that.

Typically, this sort of thing would be done like

```
DECLARE @V_ERR_REC.PROCNAME VARCHAR(4000) = @IN_PROCNAME
```

but this seems rather unnecessary based on the rest of your query.

You'd probably be better off just inserting the parameter values.

```
INSERT INTO VM1DTA.DMBATCHERRLOG 
VALUES (@IN_PROCNAME, @IN_TARNAME, @IN_CURSOR, @IN_UNIQUE_NUMBER, GETDATE(), @IN_SQLCODE, @IN_SQLERRM, @IN_REMARK)
```

However, you should also probably explicitly set which fields you're inserting these values into

```
INSERT INTO VM1DTA.DMBATCHERRLOG(Value1, Value2,..ValueN)
```